# override existing deck components those don't have Overridable annonation in spinnaker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, spinnaker

Reference

https://spinnaker.io/docs/guides/developer/plugin-creator/plugin-frontend/
https://github.com/spinnaker/deck/blob/master/packages/core/src/header/SpinnakerHeader.tsx

**spinnakerHeader.tsx**

```
import { overridableComponent } from '@spinnaker/core';
import React from 'react';
export class SpinnakerHeaderContent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("SpinnakerHeader loaded......");
    return (<h1>Overridable Component</h1>)
  }
}

export const SpinnakerHeader = overridableComponent(SpinnakerHeaderContent, 'spinnakerHeader');
```

**index.tsx**

```
import { IDeckPlugin, overrideRegistrationQueue } from '@spinnaker/core';
import { SpinnakerHeader } from './SpinnakerHeader';

export const plugin: IDeckPlugin = {
  initialize: () => {
    overrideRegistrationQueue.register(SpinnakerHeader, 'spinnakerHeader')
  }
};
```